# I'm trying to make a command with my discord bot to reply to the question with 2 random different answers (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and I can't figure it out can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Btw in new to this and every other command works

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";
const token = "token";
const randomMessage = ["Yes this is a bruh moment", "No this is not a bruh moment stop overreacting"];

bot.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} online`);
});

bot.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === "is this a bruh moment?") { 
        var response = randomMessage [Math.floor(Math.random()*randomMessage .length)];
        msg.channel.send(response);
    }
    else if(msg.content === "are you online?"){
        msg.reply("I am online and ready to be a bruh");
}});

bot.on("message", msg =>{
    if(!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == "ping"){
        msg.channel.send("pong!");
    }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: try moving the part inside your first `onMessage` event into the second one. Generally you don't want two identical events. And please share any error message you might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

> 1. **You have multiple message events**. Every and all commands should execute inside one event. Otherwise this may cause memory leaks along the way.

> 2. **You incorrectly define an array**. Arrays are defined with brackets not paranthesis.

Change

`const randomMessage = ("Yes this is a bruh moment", "No this is not a bruh moment stop overreacting")`

To

`const randomMessage = ["Yes this is a bruh moment", "No this is not a bruh moment stop overreacting"]`